# Remove all items that have duplicates in array Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have searched on here and have not found a solution. Obviously I will be corrected if I am wrong. What I am trying to do is return values that do not have a duplicates in an array.

Examples:

`myArr = [2,1,2,3]  // answer [1,3]`

`myArr = [3,1,2,2,3] // answer [1]`

I would post some code but I have not been able to figure this out myself and the only code examples I have found are for removing any duplicate values.

The possible solution above is to return no duplicates... I am trying to return values that are don't have duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array

Comment: @42shadow42: This is not about unique, though; see the examples

Comment: Oh my mistake, you want all copies of the duplicate removed not all but one thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Please show us your attempts nonetheless.

Comment: `myArr.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === a.lastIndexOf(x))` should do it

Comment: Does the order of the results matter?

Comment: no it does not. @Bergi has a ES6 solution, I do believe... Maybe an ES5 solution would help me more..

Comment: @c.reynolds: The arrow function was only for brevity, you can do the same with a function expression

Comment: You can avoid a good bit of the index searching if you only search forward from `i + 1` and track the failures in an object so that you don't search those at all. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/36ezypzw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the [optional second argument to indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find duplicate indexes. Consider that for a given element `e` and an index `i`:

1. if `e` is the first of two identical elements in the array, `indexOf(e)` will return `i` and `indexOf(e, i + 1)` will return the index of the second element.
2. if `e` is the second of two identical elements in the array, `indexOf(e)` will return the index of the first element, and `indexOf(e, i + 1)`  will return `-1`
3. if `e` is a unique element, `indexOf(e)` will return `i` and `indexOf(e, i + 1)` will return `-1`.

Therefore:

```
myArr.filter(function (e, i, a) {
  return a.indexOf(e) === i && a.indexOf(e, i + 1) === -1
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var isUnique = function(v,i,arr){
   // return true if the first occurrence is the last occurrence 
   return ( arr.indexOf(v) === arr.lastIndexOf(v) ); 
};

var uniqueVals = myArr.filter(isUnique);

console.log( uniqueVals );
```

Answer (score 0):

If is not an associative array (your case):

```
var myArr = [1,2,2,3,4,4,1,5];
var myNewArr = [];

if (myArr.length > 0 )
{
    myNewArr[0] = myArr[myArr.length-1];    
}

var count = 1;

myArr.sort();

for (var i = myArr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {

    if(myArr[i] != myArr[i-1])
    {
        myNewArr[count] = myArr[i];
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var **yourArray** = [1, 2, 1, 3];

```
        var uniqueValues = [];
        $.each(yourArray, function (i, value) { //taking each 'value' from yourArray[]
            if ($.inArray(value, uniqueValues) === -1) { 
                 uniqueValues.push(value); // Pushing the non - duplicate value into the uniqueValues[] 
            }
        });            
        console.log(uniqueValues);
```

**Result**:  [1,2,3];